# Terminal Widget for MFC/Win32 applications?

Tags: mfc, winapi, terminal, widget

I need a terminal Widget which is able to emulate a windows console and a simple VT100 terminal on Windows. Something like VTE for GTK or QConsole for QT.

Is it even possible to run a Windows Console like cmd.exe inside a child window?

Answer (score 1):

Usually a "console" or Terminal hooks up at a rs-232 interface. cmd.exe is AFAIK a native application only acting like a command line interpreter. Therefor you will not be able to use it in an child window.

Do you need a terminal emulator that communicates with a VT100? If so, there are tons of out there. If you want to write your own Interface take a look at the
[Windows PowerShell API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee706563%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). 
Another great Open Source Project for achieving something you want is [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) for Windows under MIT License. You could communicate with the VT100 using Telnet. The Windows Telnet client should be accessible using PowerShell.

Comment: PuTTY source code is unfortunately terrible complex. But yes this is exactly what i want. Just without all the encrypting stuff and as an embeddable component. The GUI stuff in PuTTY is totally hardwired with the rest of the program.

Answer (score 1):

Just call AllocConsole to create your own console window.  You can use the normal console mode CRT functions to read and write from/to it.  A more GUI friendly approach would be to just create a window with a multi-line readonly Edit control with a fixed-pitch font.

Comment: But there is much more, called Escape Sequences, i couldn't find any documentation about them (The unix VT100 etc. are all nicely documented). Even getting the Echo mode for multiplexed input/output correct is not easy.

Comment: Well, it would be your job to implement them.  It certainly has been done before, a quick google turned up http://sourceforge.net/projects/rote/